# I want to change output of API with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, api, rxjs, pipe

I have API call, where I use pipe

```
getCountriesListNights(){
    const r = this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/WorldMapDataNights?&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge + "&quarter=" + this.selectedQuarter)
      .pipe(map((res) => {return res.map((res: { id: any; countryName: any; value: any; year: any; name: string; multiPolygon: any[] }) =>({countryName: res.countryName,  id: res.id,  value: res.value, year: res.year, name: res.name, multiPolygon: res.multiPolygon  }))}))
      .subscribe(res =>{
        this.renderMapObject(res);
    });
  };
```

It works good, I can change the output, but I want to divide value by other API's value, when country name's are same in both API's. (I want to divide res.value by otherapi.value.)

what can I do now?

Comment: for example, in this API, value equals sum price and second API's value is number of items, I want to get medium price of items.

Comment: For the love of God, please format your code.

Comment: @Irakli where is second api call ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
getCountriesListNights(){
  const r = this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/WorldMapDataNights?&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge + "&quarter=" + this.selectedQuarter).pipe(map((res) => {return res.map((res: { id: any; countryName: any; value: any; year: any; name: string; multiPolygon: any[] }) =>({countryName: res.countryName,  id: res.id,  value: res.value, year: res.year, name: res.name, multiPolygon: res.multiPolygon  }))})).subscribe(res =>{
    console.log(res);
    this.renderMapObject(res);
    this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/yourSecondApiURL").subscribe(otherapiRes =>{
      const finalResult = res.value / otherapiRes .value;
      console.log(finalResult);      
    }
  });
};
```

it is not pretty and you could use something like

```
const res = await this.http.get<any>("...firstApiUrlAndMapping...").toPromise();
const res2 = await this.http.get<any>("...secondApiUrlandMapping...").toPromise();
finalResult = res.value/res2.value;
```

but both ways should work just fine.

**EDIT**

A basic example of running two http calls inside each other would be

```
const res = this.http.get<any>('https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json').subscribe(res =>{
  console.log(res);
  this.http.get<any>('https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json').subscribe(otherapiRes =>{
    console.log(otherapiRes);
    console.log('Both Results:' + res.success + ' -- ' + otherapiRes.success);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but first approach does not work for me.

Comment: It logs "NaN" and nothing more

Comment: It seems that there was a closing bracket that was missing. I have added another example in which doing two simple http calls inside each other works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to achieve the aim, you need a fulfilled response from two sources. In general, the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is giving what you need.

There are several ways to achieve your need in RxJS world.
For example, the operator `zipWith` returns a stream that notifies of an array of results (its source and its argument inputs).

A sample you can play with:

```
of('Foo')
  .pipe(
    delay(1000),
    tap(() => console.log('Foo succeeded')),
    zipWith(
      of('Bar').pipe(
        delay(2000),
        tap(() => console.log('Bar succeeded'))
      ),
      of('Baz').pipe(
        delay(2500),
        tap(() => console.log('Baz succeeded'))
      )
    ),
    // You can process and transform the outcome
    map(([foo, bar, baz]) => foo + bar + baz)
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log('All succeeded:', result);
  });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-er8zx1?file=index.ts